# Trying to understand function pointer usage in this code

Tags: c

I am trying to understand the difference between the  following two expressions and subsequently trying to use in my code:

**First**

```
#define ROM_SysCtlClockSet ((void (*)(unsigned long ulConfig))ROM_SYSCTLTABLE[23])

 // Set the clocking to run at 50 MHz from the PLL.
    //

ROM_SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                       SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);
```

**Second**

```
extern void SysCtlClockSet(unsigned long ulConfig);

SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);
```

**Definition of SysCtlClockSet as I saw is:**

```
void
SysCtlClockSet(unsigned long ulConfig)
{
    unsigned long ulDelay, ulRCC, ulRCC2;

    //
    // See if this is a Sandstorm-class device and clocking features from newer
    // devices were requested.
    //
    if(CLASS_IS_SANDSTORM && (ulConfig & SYSCTL_RCC2_USERCC2))
    {
        //
        // Return without changing the clocking because the requested
        // configuration can not be achieved.
        //
        return;
    }

    //
    // Get the current value of the RCC and RCC2 registers.  If using a
    // Sandstorm-class device, the RCC2 register reads back as zero and the
    // writes to it from within this function are ignored.
    //
    ulRCC = HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC);
    ulRCC2 = HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC2);

    //
    // Bypass the PLL and system clock dividers for now.
    //
    ulRCC |= SYSCTL_RCC_BYPASS;
    ulRCC &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC_USESYSDIV);
    ulRCC2 |= SYSCTL_RCC2_BYPASS2;

    //
    // Write the new RCC value.
    //
    HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC) = ulRCC;
    HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC2) = ulRCC2;

    //
    // See if either oscillator needs to be enabled.
    //
    if(((ulRCC & SYSCTL_RCC_IOSCDIS) && !(ulConfig & SYSCTL_RCC_IOSCDIS)) ||
       ((ulRCC & SYSCTL_RCC_MOSCDIS) && !(ulConfig & SYSCTL_RCC_MOSCDIS)))
    {
        //
        // Make sure that the required oscillators are enabled.  For now, the
        // previously enabled oscillators must be enabled along with the newly
        // requested oscillators.
        //
        ulRCC &= (~(SYSCTL_RCC_IOSCDIS | SYSCTL_RCC_MOSCDIS) |
                  (ulConfig & (SYSCTL_RCC_IOSCDIS | SYSCTL_RCC_MOSCDIS)));

        //
        // Write the new RCC value.
        //
        HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC) = ulRCC;

        //
        // Wait for a bit, giving the oscillator time to stabilize.  The number
        // of iterations is adjusted based on the current clock source; a
        // smaller number of iterations is required for slower clock rates.
        //
        if(((ulRCC2 & SYSCTL_RCC2_USERCC2) &&
            (((ulRCC2 & SYSCTL_RCC2_OSCSRC2_M) == SYSCTL_RCC2_OSCSRC2_30) ||
             ((ulRCC2 & SYSCTL_RCC2_OSCSRC2_M) == SYSCTL_RCC2_OSCSRC2_32))) ||
           (!(ulRCC2 & SYSCTL_RCC2_USERCC2) &&
            ((ulRCC & SYSCTL_RCC_OSCSRC_M) == SYSCTL_RCC_OSCSRC_30)))
        {
            //
            // Delay for 4096 iterations.
            //
            SysCtlDelay(4096);
        }
        else
        {
            //
            // Delay for 524,288 iterations.
            //
            SysCtlDelay(524288);
        }
    }

    //
    // Set the new crystal value and oscillator source.  Because the OSCSRC2
    // field in RCC2 overlaps the XTAL field in RCC, the OSCSRC field has a
    // special encoding within ulConfig to avoid the overlap.
    //
    ulRCC &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC_XTAL_M | SYSCTL_RCC_OSCSRC_M);
    ulRCC |= ulConfig & (SYSCTL_RCC_XTAL_M | SYSCTL_RCC_OSCSRC_M);
    ulRCC2 &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC2_USERCC2 | SYSCTL_RCC2_OSCSRC2_M);
    ulRCC2 |= ulConfig & (SYSCTL_RCC2_USERCC2 | SYSCTL_RCC_OSCSRC_M);
    ulRCC2 |= (ulConfig & 0x00000008) << 3;

    //
    // Write the new RCC value.
    //
    HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC) = ulRCC;
    HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC2) = ulRCC2;

    //
    // Wait for a bit so that new crystal value and oscillator source can take
    // effect.
    //
    SysCtlDelay(16);

    //
    // Set the PLL configuration.
    //
    ulRCC &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC_PWRDN | SYSCTL_RCC_OEN);
    ulRCC |= ulConfig & (SYSCTL_RCC_PWRDN | SYSCTL_RCC_OEN);
    ulRCC2 &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC2_PWRDN2);
    ulRCC2 |= ulConfig & SYSCTL_RCC2_PWRDN2;

    //
    // Clear the PLL lock interrupt.
    //
    HWREG(SYSCTL_MISC) = SYSCTL_INT_PLL_LOCK;

    //
    // Write the new RCC value.
    //
    if(ulRCC2 & SYSCTL_RCC2_USERCC2)
    {
        HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC2) = ulRCC2;
        HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC) = ulRCC;
    }
    else
    {
        HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC) = ulRCC;
        HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC2) = ulRCC2;
    }

    //
    // Set the requested system divider and disable the appropriate
    // oscillators.  This value is not written immediately.
    //
    ulRCC &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC_SYSDIV_M | SYSCTL_RCC_USESYSDIV |
               SYSCTL_RCC_IOSCDIS | SYSCTL_RCC_MOSCDIS);
    ulRCC |= ulConfig & (SYSCTL_RCC_SYSDIV_M | SYSCTL_RCC_USESYSDIV |
                         SYSCTL_RCC_IOSCDIS | SYSCTL_RCC_MOSCDIS);
    ulRCC2 &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC2_SYSDIV2_M);
    ulRCC2 |= ulConfig & SYSCTL_RCC2_SYSDIV2_M;
    if(ulConfig & SYSCTL_RCC2_DIV400)
    {
        ulRCC |= SYSCTL_RCC_USESYSDIV;
        ulRCC2 &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC_USESYSDIV);
        ulRCC2 |= ulConfig & (SYSCTL_RCC2_DIV400 | SYSCTL_RCC2_SYSDIV2LSB);
    }
    else
    {
        ulRCC2 &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC2_DIV400);
    }

    //
    // See if the PLL output is being used to clock the system.
    //
    if(!(ulConfig & SYSCTL_RCC_BYPASS))
    {
        //
        // Wait until the PLL has locked.
        //
        for(ulDelay = 32768; ulDelay > 0; ulDelay--)
        {
            if(HWREG(SYSCTL_RIS) & SYSCTL_INT_PLL_LOCK)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //
        // Enable use of the PLL.
        //
        ulRCC &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC_BYPASS);
        ulRCC2 &= ~(SYSCTL_RCC2_BYPASS2);
    }

    //
    // Write the final RCC value.
    //
    HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC) = ulRCC;
    HWREG(SYSCTL_RCC2) = ulRCC2;

    //
    // Delay for a little bit so that the system divider takes effect.
    //
    SysCtlDelay(16);
}
```

In the original  code I saw usage of both interchangeably.

Both first and Second are used for setting clock frequency, but in first one I saw this is a macro.

So is the **first**  achieving  the same thing as that of second.   After Macro expansion the **first** should become

```
((void (*)(unsigned long ulConfig))ROM_SYSCTLTABLE[23])
(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                           SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);
```

What does that mean ? what is 23 there? 
Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

One is defined through a table or pointers to functions (table name `ROM_SYSCTLTABLE`). Your function is the 24th in the table, thus the value 23 (the first has index 0).

Other is defined via an entry in the table of symbols as an externally defined function.

Both are interchangeable because the pointer equals to the address of your extern function, but it may not be always the case. The table is something like an interrupt vector table that is commonly used when accessing some *low-level* functions (drivers, etc).

Answer (score 0):

`ROM_SYSCTLTABLE` is a pointer array.

`ROM_SYSCTLTABLE[23]` is the 24th element inside that array.

`((void (*)(unsigned long ulConfig))ROM_SYSCTLTABLE[23])` this part convert that pointer to be type of `void (*)(unsigned long ulConfig)`, which is a function pointer type accepting one `unsigned long` parameter and return void.

Then calls that function with :

```
((void (*)(unsigned long ulConfig))ROM_SYSCTLTABLE[23])
(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_4 | SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                           SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ);
```